# datatables, with pagination on click doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have this code in the bottom of the page:

```
$('.checkbox-class:checkbox').on('click', function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

I have a datatable with a td with this input:

```
<input class="checkbox-class" type="checkbox" name="compartir[]" value="{{$row->id}}">
```

I can see the alert on each click of the checkbox of the first page, but when I move to the 2nd page, the script is not listening this clicks. But, if I reload the page, and move first to the 2nd page, then I do my first clicks, javascript can catch them well, but if I move to the 1st page, javascript doesn't listen them (on that, the 1st page)

I don't get it whay is happening this.

EDIT: A fiddle about it:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EBjNPW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use delegation for the event by attaching it to the table itself and only firing on the specific class type, I take it you are using JQuery as you have it in your example above, so this should serve your needs, notice how the 2nd parameter of `.on` is the className of the checkbox items in the table, this will then fire anytime a checkbox with that className inside the parent table is clicked:

```
$('#yourTable').on('click', '.checkbox-class:checkbox', function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: @pmirnd Glad to help. Have a good day. Also, this article explains what I used in my answer with more detail (https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Thanks. Can I do the same with `each`? I'm trying something like: `$('#yourTable').each('click', '.checkbox-class:checkbox', function(){`

Comment: @pmirnd I don't believe that works with `.each`, `.each` is for iterating a set of elements. But if I'm wrong on that, feel free to let me know. From what I see in the documentation here (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), that isn't valid code in your example.

Comment: Thanks mate. I've just asked it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56570595/javascript-checked-checkboxes-from-whole-table