# JavaScript, checked checkboxes from whole table

Tags: javascript

I was trying here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GbJrGq?editors=1111

```
$('#save').on('click', function(){
 alert($('#myTable').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length + ' checked');
});
```

What I need is to capture the data from every checkbox cheked in all the pages.

I was trying to "delegate" but I can't get it. My code only capture the checked cheeckbox of the current page.

Comment: I think this will help you with this one (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240409/how-to-submit-checkboxes-from-all-pages-with-jquery-datatables), the answer by user `Gyrocode.com` explains how to get all checked checkboxes from Datatables and send it to the server. Datatables removes rows from the DOM as you navigate the pages, so you need to use hidden inputs to store the hidden pages if submitting via a form or you can use Ajax to send it to the server without the hidden inputs.

Comment: Thanks mate. I read it some hours ago, actually datatables have some plugins to do the work but I don't want to add more plugins, but I will try again.

Comment: Anytime. The answer in the post I gave you doesnt need any plugins so I think it should help.

Comment: I think I love you again, it seems 
 `oTable.$('input[type="checkbox"]').serializeArray();` is doping all the job that I need (that post use it)

Comment: Glad that helped. I'm voting to close this as it could be considered a duplicate, but it's nothing against you, just trying to follow the rules of Stack Overflow.